# Table doesn't want to stretch inside div

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a `<table>` inside a `<div>` tag, which doesn't want to span as long as it needs to be. I need to specify a width in px for the `<table>` to span and thus cause the `<div>` container it is inside to scroll. Otherwise, the `<table>` just spans to a width of 100%, i.e. the width of the `<div>`.

My example is as follows:

```
<div style="width:880px; overflow:scroll;">
    <table> // I need to explicitly specify a width for it, otherwise it just span 100% which is incorrect
        <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I have specified for all the `<td>` tags a width inside my CSS.

I don't understand why the `<table>` can't determine it's own width or just respect the widths of all the `<td>` tags.

Comment: Are you trying to use a table for layout? Not a great idea. It's generally a headache to control a table's width manually, because the _point_ of a table is that its width is determined by the width of its columns, which are in turn determined by the width of the cells.

Comment: I need it to be tables, using div for a grid will make me mad. The point is that I'm giving it widths for the cells, but it ignores them.

Comment: Could you create a complete test case using [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), including CSS?

Comment: [Pretty please](http://thedogatemycareplan.files.wordpress.com/2010/10/pretty_please.jpg) make a test case?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `white-space: nowrap;` on the `td` in your table and dump a lot of text inside each td you will start seeing a scroll bar on your div.

Comment: Thanks, that helps, but some cells are now wider than others, and I need them to be the same width right through, and obviously, nothing line breaks to the next line, so this doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: that depends on the text you have in each cell, try setting a width of 100% on all your td's in the table. P.S. upvote would be appreciated if u found the answer useful.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there isn't any unintended CSS being applied to the table?  By default the table only expands to accommodate its columns.

```
<div style="width:880px; overflow:scroll; background-color: green;">
<table style="background-color: red;">
    <tr>
        <td>one</td>
        <td>two</td>
    </tr>
</table>  
</div>
```

Using this code, you can see the red table is only as big as its columns in relation to the green div as long as no other CSS is involved.

Use a tool like Firebug or IE's Developer Tools (F12) to see which styles are actually being applied to the `table` element.

[See the example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Ka4w4/)

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, I mostly work with Web Inspector on Safari, and nothing is applied to cells other than the CSS styles that I specified. It just ignores them. Unfortunately I can't post screenshots, but I can tell you that I have no clue why this is happening.